# Multipole Expansion: Why is my Taylor Series Wrong?

Tags: electrostatics, potential, voltage, multipole-expansion

Let's start by a formula. The scalar electrostatic Potential is given by:

$$\phi(\mathbf{r}) = \dfrac{1}{4\,\pi\varepsilon_0}\,\int \dfrac{\rho(\mathbf{r'})}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|}\,\mathrm{d^3 r'}$$

Now to prepare it for a Taylor Expansion it is usually written like:

$$\begin{align} \phi(\mathbf{r}) =& \dfrac{1}{4\,\pi\varepsilon_0}\,\int \dfrac{\rho(\mathbf{r'})}{\sqrt{r^2 + {r'}^2 - 2\,\mathbf{r\,r'}}}\,\mathrm{d^3 r'}\\[12pt]
=& \dfrac{1}{4\,\pi\varepsilon_0}\,\dfrac{1}{r}\,{\int} \dfrac{\rho(\mathbf{r'})}{\sqrt{1 + \frac{{r'}^2}{r^2} - 2\,\frac{\mathbf{r\,r'}}{r^2}}}\,\mathrm{d^3 r'}  \end{align}$$

At this point all sources I found declare $\epsilon  = \frac{{r'}^2}{r^2} - 2\,\frac{\mathbf{r\,r'}}{r^2}$ and expand it to second order.

I'm baffled by this approach. Is this really the same as to expand it for $r'$ at $r' = 0$ ?

Here is what I got pursuing this idea:

$$f(\mathbf{r'}) = \dfrac{1}{\left(1 + \frac{{r'}^2}{r^2} -\frac{\mathbf{r\,r'}}{r^2}\,2\right)^{1/2}}, \quad f'(\mathbf{r'}) = \dfrac{\frac{\mathbf{r}}{r^2}- \frac{\mathbf{r'}}{r^2}}{\left(1 + \frac{{r'}^2}{r^2} -\frac{\mathbf{r\,r'}}{r^2}\,2\right)^{3/2}}, \\ f''(\mathbf{r}) = \dfrac{-\frac{1}{r^2}}{\left(1 + \frac{{r'}^2}{r^2} -\frac{\mathbf{r\,r'}}{r^2}\,2\right)^{3/2}} - \dfrac{3}{2}\,\dfrac{\left(-\frac{\mathbf{r}'}{r^2}+\frac{\mathbf{r}}{r^2}\right)\,\left(-\frac{\mathbf{r}'}{r^2}+\frac{\mathbf{r}}{r^2}\right)}{\left(1 + \frac{{r'}^2}{r^2} -\frac{\mathbf{r\,r'}}{r^2}\,2\right)^{5/2}}$$

This is what it needs to long for the Taylor series:

$$\begin{align} \phi(\mathbf{r}) \approx& \dfrac{1}{4\,\pi\varepsilon_0}\,\dfrac{1}{r}\,\int \rho{(\mathbf{r'})}\,\left\{f(0) + f'(0) + \dfrac{1}{2}\,f''(0)\right\}\,\mathrm{d^3r'} \\[12pt] \phi(\mathbf{r}) \approx& \dfrac{1}{4\,\pi\varepsilon_0}\,\dfrac{1}{r}\,\int \rho(\mathbf{r'})\left\{ 1 + \dfrac{\mathbf{r}}{r^2}\,\mathbf{r'} - \dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{{r'}^2}{r^2} + \dfrac{3}{2}\,\dfrac{r^2}{r^4}\,{r'}^2\right\}\,\mathrm{d^3r'}\end{align}$$

Actually this looks really close to the actual solution that can be found in plenty:

$$\phi(\mathbf{r}) \approx \dfrac{1}{4\,\pi\varepsilon_0}\,\dfrac{1}{r}\,\int \rho(\mathbf{r'})\left\{ 1 + \dfrac{\mathbf{r}}{r^2}\,\mathbf{r'} - \dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{{r'}^2}{r^2} + \dfrac{3}{2}\,\left(\dfrac{\mathbf{r\,r'}}{r^2}\right)^2\right\}\,\mathrm{d^3r'}$$

But instead there is the disparity of $\left(\dfrac{\mathbf{r\,r'}}{r^2}\right)^2 \neq \dfrac{r^2}{r^4}\,{r'}^2$ even though it is tempting to think otherwise.

---

**Question:** Can the same solutions be obtained?

One by defining a variable (here $\epsilon$), expanding with Taylor series and plugging back in.

The other by expanding the Taylor series with respect to an already existing variable.

I've got it in my guts it both leads to the same thing, but where do I mistaken then?

Comment: they are equal to 1st order in $1/r$ and differs in in order $1/r^2$ order, that is enough to calculate the dipole moment

Comment: You moved the integration variable outside the integral? I am assuming you mean $d^3 r'$ and not $d^3 r$ right?

Comment: Yea, sorry, little typo while typing all of it: I meant $\mathrm{d^3 r'}$. What do you mean by differing in second order? In fact the Multipole expansion shouldn't differ, it should give the same series by whatever approach you take. The great question is, where does this little deviation on the way I took come from.

Comment: I'm not sure if you've handled the multivariable Taylor expansion correctly. To expand $f(\vec{r})$ about $\vec{r}=\vec{a}$ to second order, you should have something like
$$
f(\vec{r}) = f(\vec{a}) + D^T \vec X + \frac{1}{2} \vec{X}^T H \vec{X}
$$
where $\vec{X}=\vec{r}-\vec{a}$, $D=\nabla f(\vec{a})$ is the gradient of $f$ evaluated at $\vec{a}$, and $H_{ij} = \partial^2 f(\vec{a})/\partial x^i \partial x^j$ is the [Hessian matrix](https://tinyurl.com/2p8e2284) (evaluated at $\vec{a}$). The advantage of the $\epsilon$ approach is that you are expanding a function of a single variable.

Comment: This sounds really reasonable as well, but I guess the precondition was wrong all the time: the lowest formula for the potential $\phi$ only should hold if the series is expanded for $\epsilon$ and plucked back in. Even if I event don't end on the same result, by doing exactly that.